# How to ignore csv fields in phpmyadmin import

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have the following csv....

```
6353,test
7855,test2
```

I only want the second field to be imported. Ive tried the following for the specified column names in phpmyadmin

```
null, product_name
```

But no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply write the columns you don't need into variables.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv'
INTO TABLE t1
(column1, @var1)
```